# Android - Do a simple calculation

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a **EditText**, **TextView** and a **Button**. The user type a number into the **EditText**. I then want it to be divided by 100 once the user click on the button and display the answer back in the **TextView**.

Here is my layout (**activity_main.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tv_numb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:hint="Provide a number"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_doCalc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_numb"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_doCalc"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Answer" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText editTextNumb;
private Button buttonCalc;
private TextView tvAnswer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextNumb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_numb);
    buttonCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_doCalc);
    tvAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_answer);

    //I think this is where my problem is-------
    final int result = (editTextNumb.getText().toString())/100;
    //

        buttonCalc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tvAnswer.setText(result);

            }});
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Help doing what?  You haven't shown us your code, nor explained what problem you're having with it.  Without any context regarding what you're stuck on, it's not possible for us to un-stick you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
              try
              {
                 int result = Integer.parseInt(mEdit.getText().toString())/100;
                // show it to them
                Log.v("EditText", "result is "+result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"result is "+result,     
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
              catch (final NumberFormatException e) 
              {
                  // tell them they didnt enter a valid number
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter a valid number",     
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: I got a error "Wrong 2nd argument type" with Log.v("EditText", result);

Comment: @H.Brooks please check the edit

Comment: ah great, and how can I display it on the screen, currently it only display in the log, not the emulator.

Comment: @H.Brooks, Please try the edited version that will show the result in a  toast message

Comment: can not resolve activity 'getActivity()'

Comment: @H.Brooks instead of getActivity() type your Activity name for example :-Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
    "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate it.